# Patterns or options for public application, such as a discussion forum, without heavy license costs?

Tags: force.com, licenses, app-development, design-patterns

Does anyone know of any development patterns or platform features/options to allow a developer to create a Force.com application, such as a discussion forum, and not have to pay for each and every user that registered/used that application?

We've considered just using an external authentication mechanism but that prevents us from using the built-in security and authorization features of the Force.com platform.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between per-login and per-member licensing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building functionality like this would most likely break the T&C of the salesforce contract for anyone using this functionality. Salesforce authentication comes with rich, secure and well-tested functionality which you should rely on rather than attempt to bypass to decrease licensing costs.

Salesforce is an enterprise product and platform,  but it's not intended to be the best or most suited platform for everything. I would either opt for a customer community and fully leverage the functionality, or go for an alternative with less or different possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the ability to login using native features, then you will have to pay for licenses for those that log in.......